# Error while opening LXTerminal in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pi-3b+, lxterminal

[image]I have got a problem. I am giving power to RPI 3 B+ and waiting for starting OS. Then when I open LXTerminal there are symbols with error of /etc/inputrc(see screenshot in down). Please help me, and say how can I solve this problem.
Best Regards,
Mammadli Elnur

Comment: It looks like you are connecting to the pi by VNC. Do you get the same error when you hook a monitor and keyboard directly to the rpi?

Comment: Emmmmm. I don't tested it yet.

Comment: Stop. oh, Yes,  I have got these error.

Comment: And can you send me /etc/inputrc code please?